# Another invalid genesis file error

Tags: go-ethereum

I am getting this error this error at creation of genesis block:

```
[niko@localhost go-ethereum]$ cat /home/niko/saved-niko-home/aet/genesis-test.json
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 777,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": 131072,
    "gasLimit": 2100000,
    "alloc": {
        "0db459d44280be8d8999b32cc1b22228ad803fa1" : {"balance":1000}
    }
}
[niko@localhost go-ethereum]$ build/bin/geth --datadir=/home/niko/saved-niko-home/aet init /home/niko/saved-niko-home/aet/genesis-test.json 
Fatal: invalid genesis file: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Genesis.alloc of type *math.HexOrDecimal256
[niko@localhost go-ethereum]$
```

Validated with all online JSON validators out there, strict and non-strict, doesn't show any error. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JSON doesn't have a numeric type with the precision required for some fields in the genesis.json. A workaround is to use strings.

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 777,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "131072",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "0db459d44280be8d8999b32cc1b22228ad803fa1" : {"balance":"1000"}
    }
}
```